# Substitution von Substantiven durch Adjektive

Tags: adjective, capitalization

Ich habe eine Frage zu folgendem Satz, bei dem ich mir über die Groß- und Kleinschreibung unsicher bin. Es geht um die "Substantivierung" eines Adjektivs:

Der FTSE 100 und der DAX haben die höchste Autokorrelationsfunktion, während der Nikkei  225 die niedrigste(?) aufweist.

Wird in diesem Fall "niedrigste" klein oder groß geschrieben ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In diesem Fall wird "niedrigste" klein geschrieben.

Die Regel besagt, dass wenn nach einem Adjektiv ein Substantiv eingespart worden ist, klein geschrieben wird (z. B. [Duden 73](https://www.duden.de/sprachwissen/rechtschreibregeln/Gro%C3%9F-%20und%20Kleinschreibung#K73)).

Das Adjektiv "niedrigste" bezieht sich weiterhin auf die "Autokorrelationsfunktion", was durch Ergänzung geprüft werden kann:

> Der FTSE 100 und der DAX haben die höchste Autokorrelationsfunktion, während der Nikkei 225 die niedrigste Autokorrelationsfunktion aufweist.

Comment: Super vielen Dank, insbesondere auch für die Erklärung ! Leider kann ich deine Antwort nicht upvoten reputations < 15